# What is the curl equivalent command in powershell for uploading the apk file?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to perform CI/CD using Perfecto and hence I am trying to upload a file to perfecto when my Bamboo build is finished.

I was trying with the following cURL command when we have a Linux server.

```
curl -X POST --upload-file test.apk 'https://****.perfectomobile.com/services/repositories/media/PRIVATE:test.apk?operation=upload&user=<email>&password=<password>&overwrite=true'
```

Now our server is changed to Windows and hence I want a powershell script which I can use as an Inline Scripts in Bamboo.

Can you please tell me what is an equivalent script in Powershell for windows.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Gather your information.
$email = "myEmail@website.com";
$password = "powershellR0cks!";
$subDomain = "****";
$url = "https://$subDomain.perfectomobile.com/services/repositories/media/PRIVATE:test.apk?operation=upload&user=$email&password=$password&overwrite=true";
$filePath = ".\test.apk";

# Make the request.
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Method Post -InFile $filePath -ContentType "application/octet-stream";

# Check for success.
if (-not ($response.StatusCode -eq 200)) {
    throw "There was an error uploading the APK manifest.";
}
```

You may want to check the value of `-ContentType`, but I think that's correct.  You don't necessarily need to include the scheme (HTTPS) if you don't want to, and semicolons in PowerShell are optional, but you can include them if you want.

The `$response` variable is an `HtmlWebResponseObject` that has the content of the response, the status code, and a bunch of other useful info.  You can check out the available properties and methods on the object by running `$response | Get-Member`.

Finally, the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet also has other parameters that may be useful to you, such as `-Credential`, `-Headers`, and more.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1

As a side-note, if you run `Get-Alias -Name "curl"`, you can see that anytime you use `curl` in PowerShell, you're really just calling `Invoke-WebRequest`.  You can use the `curl` alias if you want, but it's generally not a good idea to  use aliases in automation since they can be modified or deleted.

Comment: I have added one more line to make it work. _[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12_